# Getting all values for a key in nested JSON not working in Lodash +Typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

My sample JSON Data

```
var data = {"a":"Hello",
            "b":{"a":"World"},
            "c":[{"a":"Good"},{"d":"Morning"}]}
```

And my code snippet

```
var _ = require('lodash');

function _generate_values(data, key){
    if (Array.isArray(data)) { 
        return _.map(data,function(x, idx){
            _generate_values(x, key)
          }
        )
    }else if(typeof data==="object"){
        return _.map(
            _.keys(data),
            function(x){ 
                if(x===key){
                    _.get(data,x) # console here gives me desired values
                }else{
                    _generate_values(_.get(data, x), key)
                }
                
            }
        )
    }else{
        return null
    }
}

function find_values_(data, key, paths =false)
{

   return( _.chain(_generate_values(data, key))
        .compact()
        .value()
   )
}

find_values_(data,'a')
```

I am able to console the values but not getting returned from `_generate_values` . What is the mistake I am doing here.

Comment: The callback you provide to `.map()` should `return` the value you want to transform the currently iterated value to.

Comment: You never return anything but `null`.  Change `_generate_values` to `return _generate_values`.

Comment: I didn't get that I have provided return for all `.map()` in `_generate_values`

Comment: @curiousguy On line 6, `_generate_values(x, key)` should be `return _generate_values(x, key)`.  Similar for line 14 and 16.  The function passed to `map` must return a value.  Right now it's returning `undefined`.